# Are there possible security concerns with exposing system.dll via web service?

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, dynamic-code

I'm curious what damage someone could do with just access to the System.dll namespace in C#.

I was playing around with dynamic code compiling and created a simple website which allows me to type in C# code.  This is passed via web service to a class which complies and runs the code in a new thread and returns (code must return a string) the result via the WS and is displayed on the web page.

Right now I have a simple check to abort the thread if it runs for more than 5 seconds to ensure something simple like an infinite loop won't crash things.

"Hypothetically" speaking if I published this web application could someone do serious/any damage to a web server with just access to System.dll?

**bonus points for some sort of example! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can create a new Thread (mscorlib.dll) that wont comply with your 5 second rule, download a remove binary with WebClient (System.dll) and executing it using Process (System.dll).
2. Just a loop which creates thousands of forever-looping threads would consume a lot of cpu time.

Comment: @simon-svensson right on! I was thinking by only importing System would stop stuff like that, but of course you can directly reference System.Net namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Not if you run in partial trust and limit permissions appropriately.  If you don't... well, there are few bounds to the capabilities of `System.dll` and `mscorlib.dll`, since that's where reflection is implemented.

Comment: I'll have to try an example to see how partial trust can be implemented on the loaded assembly. Thanks.